# OpenWhisk messaging package - messageHubProduce unstable

Tags: message-hub, openwhisk

I'm trying to use the "whisk.system/messaging" and trying to use the method messageHubProduce.

I created a bind to this package, and tried to use a simple call with postman.
Using the documentation, I created a simple json and did a call, but the method is really unstable. The same call sometimes return as a success, sometimes returns a timeout and sometimes as a "No brokers available".
I now the implementation of this code is on python. Have anyone with the same symptoms I getting?

This is the message I'm sending.

`{
           "topic": "mytopic",
           "value": "MyMessage",
           "blocking": false
}`

These are the results for the same call

messageHubProduce 446d59eb816b4b34a52374a6a24f3efe
{ "error": "The action exceeded its time limits of 60000 milliseconds." }

messageHubProduce 4213b6a495bc4c5aa7af9e299ddd8fcd
{ "success": true }

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. We are aware of this issue and we are working with the Message Hub team to get it resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working closely with the Message Hub team, we have deployed an updated `messageHubProduce` action which should address your stability and performance issues.

Additionally, to provide real-time feedback please feel free to join us on Slack: https://openwhisk.incubator.apache.org/slack.html